# Overriding PhoneAccentColor doesn't work

Tags: windows-phone-7, resourcedictionary

I just want to customize the `PhoneAccentColor` within my application, but it doesn't seem to work.

I made App Resources looking like:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Utils/Converters.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ViewModels:ViewModelLocator x:Key="ViewModelLocator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
        <Resources:ResourcesWrapper x:Key="ResWrapper" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

And in the Styles.xaml I redefined the PhoneAccentColor like this:

```
<Color x:Key="PhoneAccentColor">#FFFF0000</Color>
```

But for any reason the default phone accent color is still used. 
For example I'm using the PerformanceProgressBar from the toolkit which still uses the default color instead of the definied red.

Is there anything I missed?

Comment: Solved: Seems like you also have to override <SolidColorBrush x:Key="PhoneAccentBrush" Color="{StaticResource PhoneAccentColor}"/> within the Styles.xaml.

Comment: You should put this as an answer then vote it up so others can see your question is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: Seems like you also have to override  within the Styles.xaml.